# Are there grants supporting sabbatical year in US?

Tags: soft-question, career, advice, grants

I am a tenured mathematician at a university outside of the US. I would be interested to spend my sabbatical year in one of the US universities.

**Are there grants I can apply to partially support my sabbatical year?**

Sorry if my question is not appropriate for this site. In that case, please let me know which site is appropriate.

Comment: The research content of this question seems limited.

Comment: @MikhailKatz The "soft-question" tag is described as "Questions that are about ... job of a research mathematician, without being mathematical problems...". This seems to fit the description. Perhaps the description should change, if the community consensus is to discourage such questions (though I personally see little wrong with it).

Comment: Normally, generic academia questions that do not have a specific maths component are better suited for [academia.stackexchange.com](https://academia.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I don't think the question is appropriate for here. But I also think it is a little unclear: I'm guessing the intended question is "are there grants from US institutions/government agencies supporting a sabbatical year in the US?"; but for example it is certainly possible that your home institution/country has grants which support sabbatical years many places, including the US.

Comment: https://www.simonsfoundation.org/grant/simons-fellows-in-mathematics/

Comment: @DavidZureick-Brown That is useful only if OP is in Canada.

Comment: @BorisBukh, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463149/are-there-grants-supporting-sabbatical-year-in-us#comment1202395_463149), I think that Simons grants are in the US.  (I don't see at a glance at their website any geographical limitations, but I know I've held a grant from them in the US.)  Another useful Simons grant, actually now treated as a gift, is https://www.simonsfoundation.org/grant/travel-support-for-mathematicians .

Comment: @LSpice From eligibility "A Simons Fellow in Mathematics must have a teaching or administrative tenured position at ... U.S. or Canadian college or university ... ". So, the only non-US country that OP can be tenured at and apply to this scheme is Canada.

Comment: @BorisBukh, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463149/are-there-grants-supporting-sabbatical-year-in-us#comment1202399_463149), ah, I see, thanks.  I read the title about "grants supporting sabbatical year in US" as meaning "grants in the US supporting a sabbatical year", but I now see from the body that that was exactly wrong.

Comment: @BorisBukh the tag information describes the topic/subfield intended by the tag, but doesn't mean by any means that the topic is appropriate for MO, or that every question that fits in that topic is appropriate for MO.

Answer (score 7):

There is [Fulbright scholars program](https://fulbrightscholars.org/non-us-scholars).

Answer (score 7):

The normal way to do this would be to have a collaborator at a US institution invite you for an extended stay. That university could even give you a courtesy appointment like "Visiting Scholar." Your co-author's grant could pay for your travel, accommodation, etc. Presumably you have a specific university in mind, and perhaps even a specific person you'd like to work with, so the next step would be to reach out to them.

An alternative way to get to the US during your sabbatical, with funding for an extended stay, would be to apply to an [MSRI program](https://dac.berkeley.edu/math-sciences-research-institute-msri), an [IAS program](https://www.ias.edu/programs-outreach), or some other organization offering a semester-long program with thematic conferences (potentially, [ICERM](https://icerm.brown.edu/programs/) could do something like this but I don't think they currently are).